# How to use GLSL with gstreamer?

Tags: glsl, gstreamer

I'm about GStreamer and GLSL, and I want to build a project to view side-by-side stereoscopic sideos with GStreamer and Oculus Rift. There is a [link](https://lubosz.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/view-side-by-side-stereoscopic-video-with-gstreamer-and-oculus-rift/) talk about this which has a GLSL code in it. But I don't know how to use this code with in GStreamer's code. Could anybody help me ?

Comment: Hello @Sheldon. Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please update your question to add some code. Also, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a filter element. Take a look at the gl elements we have here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/ext/gl

Here is a design doc for the stereo/multiview support in gstreamer:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/docs/design/part-stereo-multiview-video.markdown